# How do you make a div have an active or visited style?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, styles

I am trying to make my navigation turn larger and orange when it is the active nav however what happens is after click on it the design shows up then goes back to the default unclicked design.

**This is my Code:**

```css
a.urlCount {
    @include circle (20px, $white, inline-block);
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: $gray;
    text-align: center;
    color: $gray;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a.urlCount:hover{
    @include circle (20px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #f56c2f;
    text-align: center;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a.urlCount:visited{
    @include circle (23px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #f56c2f;
    text-align: center;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

a.urlCount:active{
    @include circle (23px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #f56c2f;
    text-align: center;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

a.urlCount--active{
    @include circle (23px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #f56c2f;
    text-align: center;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="urlNavigation">
    <span class="navTitle text__bold">SCAN RESULT OF URL</span>
  <a class="urlCount text__bold" [routerLinkActive]="'urlCount--active'" (click)="initializeTableData(1)">{{ 1 }}</a>
  <a class="urlCount text__bold" (click)="initializeTableData(2)">{{ 2 }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to consider using `DOM` and adding an onclick function to change the syles.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with Javascript or jQuery by adding a class to the clicked element and defining the desired CSS styles for that class.

---

### **Javascript**

First you have to loop through all `.urlCount` elements to attach the event listeners (and its handlers).

In the handler it is important to first remove that class from the previously active element. To prevent an error for the case that no element is active you need to check before if such an active element exists. Alternatively you could loop through all `.urlCount` elements in a `for` loop and remove the class from each element.

```js
if (!!document.querySelector('.active')) {
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
}
```

*with `!!` (double negation) you convert a value to a boolean, for example `undefined` to `false` or an (existing) `object` to `true`*

Last you just need to add the `.active` class to the clicked element:

```js
this.classList.add('active');
```

**Working example:**

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.urlCount');

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!!document.querySelector('.active')) {
      document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

```css
a.urlCount {
  @include circle (20px, $white, inline-block);
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: $gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: $gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.urlCount:hover {
  @include circle (20px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #f56c2f;
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.urlCount.active {
  @include circle (23px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #f56c2f;
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="urlNavigation">
  <span class="navTitle text__bold">SCAN RESULT OF URL</span>
  <a class="urlCount text__bold" [routerLinkActive]="'urlCount--active'" (click)="initializeTableData(1)">{{ 1 }}</a>
  <a class="urlCount text__bold" (click)="initializeTableData(2)">{{ 2 }}</a>
</div>
```

---

### **jQuery**

If you are using jQuery the code gets far simpler. The `for` loop isn't necessary anymore, because you can simply add the event listener to the selection of all `.urlCount` elements:

```js
$('.urlCount').on('click', function(){...});
```

And you can omit the if statement for the existence of an active element because you can simply remove the `.active` class from all `.urlCount` elements in one step (*without a for loop*):

```js
$('.urlCount').removeClass('active');
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('.urlCount').on('click', function(){
  $('.urlCount').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
a.urlCount {
  @include circle (20px, $white, inline-block);
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: $gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: $gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.urlCount:hover {
  @include circle (20px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #f56c2f;
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.urlCount.active {
  @include circle (23px, #f56c2f, inline-block);
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #f56c2f;
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="urlNavigation">
  <span class="navTitle text__bold">SCAN RESULT OF URL</span>
  <a class="urlCount text__bold" [routerLinkActive]="'urlCount--active'" (click)="initializeTableData(1)">{{ 1 }}</a>
  <a class="urlCount text__bold" (click)="initializeTableData(2)">{{ 2 }}</a>
</div>
```